# Why is Google not indexing my forum?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I have [this](http://www.heliumscraper.com) web site that as you can see on the top right has is a "Forums" button that links to my forums.

My problem is that if, for instance, I make a Google search "site:heliumscraper.com answers" I don't get any result, even though the word "answers" is in the forum's board index and it has been there for a few months already.

I don't have a robots file. I also uploaded a sitemap to Google that contained the forum. I'm thinking the problem might be the fact that the only link from my main page to the forum opens in a new window. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Maybe sign up for [Google Webmasters](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I see that Google does index your forum page. Try searching "site:heliumscraper.com online"

However, when you look at what [Google actually cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aEBAEsz1U8iEJ%3aheliumscraper.com/forum/%20site%3aheliumscraper.com%20online), you do not see any forum listings. That's why the query "site:heliumscraper.com answers" didn't turn up anything.

Since I do not use phpBB, I can't help you with an exact solution. However, it looks like this seems to be an issue in the phpBB system. Searching for "phpbb google index" turns up some other forum questions, where people are also complaining that phpBB is not indexed. (Sorry to be not much of a help)

Answer (score 2):

You're halfway to finding the issue.

- check with Google Webmaster Tools to see if any HTML issues are showing
- also check to see what number of pages are being indexed vs being submitted
- then do a [fetch as googlebot](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=158587) test from inside GWT to see what gets returned

Answer (score 0):

The index page and forum hub pages are in the index. Most of the individual threads are not. Another way of doing a random sample of this is to paste a URL into Google and see if it returns something. The fact that Google is indexing the forum is good but it is having problems hitting the inner pages and I think this is because of the URLs...although as mention by Asa it is worth hitting the forums. I think having an XML sitemap that is dynamically generated and submitted to Google webmaster tools regularly will help with this (up your crawl rate too). Also, if there is something that can be done about the URLs (rewriting) for phpBB I would do that. Good luck =)